# Fix citation for world bank report to match Cite Them Right 10th edition to match report instead to article style

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I'm trying to cite "Foreign Direct Investment, Backward Linkages, and Productivity Spillovers", a World Bank report using the Cite Them Right 10th edition - Harvard style. When I use the \cite function in overleaf I get (Jordaan et al., 2020), instead of (World Bank, 2020) and I need help fixing this.

I'm using Zotero to manage my references so I don't want to change it manually if I can help it. Thanks

This is the code I am using to format my references in Latex.

```
% bibliography-related packages
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{har2nat}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage{filecontents}
```

The code in my bib file is

```
@techreport{jordaan_foreign_2020,
title = {Foreign {Direct} {Investment}, {Backward} {Linkages}, and {Productivity} {Spillovers}},
url = {https://ideas.repec.org/p/wbk/wboper/33761.html},
abstract = {No abstract is available for this item.},
language = {en},
number = {33761},
urldate = {2020-06-15},
institution = {The World Bank},
author = {Jordaan, Jacob and Douw, Wim and Qiang, Christine Zhenwei},
month = may,
year = {2020},
note = {Publication Title: World Bank Other Operational Studies},
keywords = {FDI}
}
```

Comment: In cases like this I think it is perfectly fine to give the author names instead of the corporate entity. If you insist on having "World Bank" as author in the citation, the easiest way is to put `author = {{World Bank}},` in the author field instead of the actual author names.

Comment: Great thanks, didn't think of changing the author name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this I think it is perfectly fine to give the author names instead of the corporate entity.

If you insist on having "World Bank" as author in the citation, the easiest way is to put it into the author field instead of the actual author names.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{har2nat}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{jordaan_foreign_2020,
  author      = {Jordaan, Jacob and Douw, Wim and Qiang, Christine Zhenwei},
  title       = {Foreign Direct Investment, Backward Linkages, and Productivity Spillovers},
  year        = {2020},
  month       = may,
  number      = {33761},
  institution = {The World Bank},
  address     = {Washington, DC},
  url         = {https://openknowledge.worldbank.org/handle/10986/33761},
  urldate     = {2020-06-15},
  keywords    = {FDI},
}
@techreport{worldbank_2020,
  author      = {{World Bank}},
  title       = {Foreign Direct Investment, Backward Linkages, and Productivity Spillovers},
  year        = {2020},
  month       = may,
  number      = {33761},
  institution = {The World Bank},
  address     = {Washington, DC},
  url         = {https://openknowledge.worldbank.org/handle/10986/33761},
  urldate     = {2020-06-15},
  keywords    = {FDI},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\citep{jordaan_foreign_2020,worldbank_2020}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Jordaan, J., Douw, W. and Qiang, C. Z. (2020), Foreign direct investment, backward linkages, and productivity spillovers, Technical Report 33761, The World Bank, Washington, DC.//World Bank (2020), Foreign direct investment, backward linkages, and productivity spillovers, Technical Report 33761, The World Bank, Washington, DC.]